# Symfony 3 form : display old inputs values in twig after submitting a form with invalid values

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony

I'm trying to get old inputs values and display it as default values using twig.

With something like this :

```
{{ form_widget(form.numeroCIN, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', value:'{% if form.vars.old.fieldName %} {{form.vars.old.fieldName}} {% endif %}'}}) }}
```

Comment: Do You want to display values from database or You want display data in inputs after correctly submitted form ? In both case You can transfer data in controller for example `$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entityObject)`

Comment: No ! i just want redirect to my form with old values when the form is invalid instead of just displaying the error messages. 
That we can do it in Laravel using blade with : {{ old("inputName") }}

Comment: I think that using angularJS that cause me this problèm :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a Middleware Class:

```
class OldInputMiddleware extends Middleware
```

{

```
public function __invoke ($request, $response, $next)
{

    $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('old', $_SESSION['old']);
    $_SESSION['old'] = $request->getParams();

    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;

}
```

}

Register it into App.php (my default bootstrap file)

`$app->add(new \App\Middleware\OldInputMiddleware($container));`):

After, with Twig Module installed you can call the old value of input (after post failing):

```
value="{{old.Name}}
```